# store and access last searches xamarin forms

Tags: xml, listview, search, autocomplete, xamarin.forms

So I have this project in which I need to add search functionality to a ListView. I'm using a different page (as done in sample EmployeeDirectory from xamarin - https://github.com/pemq/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/EmployeeDirectory) and there I only need to display (if any are available) the last 5 searches the user made, in a listView, to keep things simple.

Now the problem is (and funny how one can always come across something so simple and foolishly complicated with xamarin -_-) I came across a solution which is giving me enough trouble which is storing these searches in an xml file in the app, and access them afterwards in order to show them to the user, and allow some interaction (like selecting one of the searches and display it's results in the main listView for the items...

I know, I know, I'm trying to use tools made for little kids games in order to build super-styled late hip professional apps for business consumers, but hey, I'm not the company boss, so I just have to deal with that and perform as much miracles as required (even though there's no such thing ._.)...

Any suggestions, please, on how to perform something like this? Where in the app can I store this xml file I need, and how to access it? So far this was the only useful result I could find in the web https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24275/search-bar-or-autocomplete-for-xamarin-forms - just it yourselves...

Once again I know I'm asking too much of you, and thanks in advance to anyone that can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Forms has a built in [storage mechanism](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) that you can use for persisting small bits of data

```
Application.Current.Properties ["searchHistory"] = searchXml.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks Jason. see my problem with the app properties is that after successfully saving my list of ItemSearch (the obj that contains the ID and Text of a specific search) I couldn't read from it... meaning, I'd have to to something like: 0|some search text?1|some other search text?, and in the end remove last char and separate by ? then by | and all this would cost me time and resources (it's a mobile app). is it possible to follow your suggestion but something like: searchXml.ToJson()? see, it's just that not only I can't go that far with xamarin, I'm also new to programming (a year of exp...)

Comment: I know I can't just set that .ToJson, I just meant serializing it first to json, then to string. (about working with JSON I already learned a bit more than xml - I was just running out of chars in the previous comment)...

Comment: json is just a string.  But you could also just create 5 "buckets" (searchHistory1, searchHistory2, etc) to store the last 5 searches in if you want to keep it simple.

Comment: ok, also I looked it up again and it seems the Properties is actually an IDictionary storing a pair string, object, meaning I could (possibly) store anything there, also meaning I could store the List of ItemSearch objs. I'll try both solutions, see what gets done faster and easier :) thank you very much Jason.